# Sheaf cohomology on a fiber product of schemes.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homology-cohomology

This is 18.2.8 in Vakil's Foundations of Algebraic Geometry.

Let $X$ and $Y$ be quasicompact and separated schemes over a field $k$, and let $F$ be a quasicoherent sheaf on $X$, and $G$ be a quasicoherent sheaf on $Y$. Then, prove that $H^m(X \times_k Y, \pi_1^* F \otimes \pi_2^* G) = \oplus_{p + q = m} H^p(X, F) \otimes_k H^q(Y, G)$.

My attempt is: first I covered $X$ and $Y$ with finitely many affine open sets $(U_i)_{i \in I}$ and $(V_j)_{j \in J}$. Then , I took the tensor product of the two Cech complexes, and showm that the total complex of the resulting double complex is the Cech complex for $\pi_1^* F \otimes \pi_2^* G$.

The last step is to find relate the cohomology of a tensor product of complexes with the cohomology of the original complexes. This is where I got stuck. On the second page of the spectral sequence, I get $E^{i , j}_2 = H^i(X, F) \otimes_k H^j(Y, G)$. But I don't know whether or not the spectral sequence converges here, and if not, how to compute the third page.

Comment: This is called the universal coefficient theorem. By the way, such a direct sum decomposition is equivalent to the degeneracy of spectral sequence.

Comment: @fyx1123581347 Is it not the [Künneth formula](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0BEC)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution in Example 3.6 : [here](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Ehutching/teach/215b-2011/ss.pdf).

The idea is that $E^{p, q}_2 = H^p(X, F) \otimes H^q(Y, G)$, which is a quotient of $ker(d_p) \otimes ker(d_q)$, so $d_p \otimes 1$ and $1 \otimes d_q$ both send them to 0. Therefore, the morphisms on all pages after the second page of the spectral sequence are 0, so the spectral sequence converges there.

Answer (score 0):

I’m being elliptic, so I encourage you to write the details out.

Let $k$ be a field and $X,Y$ be two bounded complexes of $k$-vector spaces (such as your alternating Cech complexes). We want to show that the canonical map $H(X) \otimes H(Y) \rightarrow H(X \otimes Y)$ is an isomorphism (all tensor products are over $k$).

First assume that $Y$ is a single vector space – then it’s easy to check. It follows (by direct sum) that the statement still holds if the differentials of $Y$ vanish.

For general $Y$, we have an exact sequence of complexes $0 \rightarrow Y’ \rightarrow Y \rightarrow Y’’ \rightarrow 0$, with $Y’$ and $Y’’$ having null differentials. We then tensor the cohomology LES with  $H(X)$, creating the long exact sequence $(E_1)$. But $0 \rightarrow X \otimes Y’ \rightarrow X \otimes Y \rightarrow X \otimes Y’’ \rightarrow 0$ is exact as well, and we call $(E_2)$ its cohomology LES.

The “canonical morphism” produces a morphism from $(E_1)$ to $(E_2)$, which is an isomorphism at all terms involving $Y’$ or $Y’’$ (by assumption). By the five lemma, it’s an isomorphism. QED

Comment: There are some things I don't understand about your answer : $0 \rightarrow X\otimes Y' \rightarrow  X\otimes Y \rightarrow  X\otimes Y'' →0$ is the exact sequence of double complexes, so the LES is for their total complexes, right? Also, what's the morphism between $E_1$ and $E_2$? There are no double complexes involved when constructing $E_1$. Finally, is there a way to show directly that the spectral sequence converges on page 2, and avoid having to take long exact sequences?

Comment: 1) yes, sorry for being unclear. Every time I’m mentioning the tensor product of two complexes $A^{\cdot}$ and $B^{\cdot}$, I mean $\left(\bigoplus_{p+q=n}{A^p \otimes B^q}\right)_{n}$ with the appropriate differentials. 2) it’s just the natural morphism $H^{\cdot}(A) \otimes H^{\cdot}(B) \rightarrow H^{\cdot}(A \otimes B)$ for any complexes $A, B$. 3) I don’t know. I’m not very comfortable with spectral sequences yet.